# Calculating running count and percentages from long-type data

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a dataset that looks like so:

| ID_SALE | PRODUCT | STORE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SE_056 | AAA | NORTH |
| XT-558 | AAA | NORTH |
| 8547Y | AAA | NORTH |
| TY856 | BBB | NORTH |
| D-895 | BBB | SOUTH |
| ER5H | CCC | SOUTH |
| 5F6F-GD | CCC | SOUTH |
| 65-FFD | TTT | SOUTH |
| 56-YU | UUU | SOUTH |

I want to be able to plot a table that will show the count of each `PRODUCT` and the contribution of the global percentage of each `PRODUCT` as well as the cumulative percentage like so:

| PRODUCT | Subtotal | Percentage | running % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 3 | 0,33333333 | 0,33333333 |
| BBB | 2 | 0,22222222 | 0,55555556 |
| CCC | 2 | 0,22222222 | 0,77777778 |
| TTT | 1 | 0,11111111 | 0,88888889 |
| UUU | 1 | 0,11111111 | 1 |

I also want to be able to have a filter in the PowerBI sheet that will filter by `STORE` so if I choose "NORTH" my table will show the following:

| PRODUCT | Subtotal | Percentage | running % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 3 | 0,75 | 0,75 |
| BBB | 1 | 0,25 | 1 |

Although I have used the quick-measure feature to get the cumulative total I get get it to sort in order my data and so I figured that DAX is the only way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Assuming your table is named "Table".

```
Subtotal = COUNTROWS('Table')

Percentage = [Subtotal]/CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Table'),REMOVEFILTERS())

running % = 
VAR cursor = MAX('Table'[PRODUCT])
RETURN 
CALCULATE( [Percentage], REMOVEFILTERS(),'Table'[PRODUCT]<= cursor)
```

Comment: Hey! David thanks a lot I have a question what does the ´REMOVEFILTERS()´ function do and , if I filter by other columns on the actual sheet will your code allow for this table to update accordingly ?

Comment: It removes any filters from the evaluation context. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/removefilters-function-dax

Comment: David your code works 100% but when I try to sort the table to show the higthest subtotal the running% gest mixed up and wont add the values in the new sort order selected

Comment: any thoughts on how to fix this ?by the way THANKS A LOT MAN

Comment: The sort order for the running percentage is in the measure itself - 'Table'[PRODUCT]<= cursor. I suggest learning some basic DAX fundamentals so you can understand the code.